# Get Details About iOS App Refund

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

***BACKGROUND*** 
I'm helping a 3rd party host 3 apps that they paid me to write (they've given me access to their Apple credentials - created expressly for this app - in order to manage the iTunesConnect process).

Because of this, I get access to all of the sales data, etc. through iTunesConnect. We currently have all 3 apps released, two of which are first-time releases and one of which has been on the store for a few months and updated a couple of times. The first app was initially released with a $1.99 price point as an introductory price, which went up to $3.99 after about a month.

***ACTUAL QUESTION***
I just got my daily report from AppFigures.com (highly recommended, by the way; it's a relatively cheap way to get a good amount of automated data and analytics about app sales), and I noticed that app #1 had 3 refunds yesterday. We've only had 7 refunds ever, and all 3 of these refunds were originally purchased at the $1.99 price point. Therefore, this has made me very curious as to why they got the refund NOW. We had bugs earlier on that have subsequently been resolved by updates, so I don't understand why someone would have a legitimate reason to ask for and receive a refund at this point.

**Please note**: I'm fully aware that I'll never get the information to tie back directly to the user. I understand why, but it's a bit of a shame (and it's why we included a voluntary contact/feedback mechanism in the app itself). I'm just wondering if I can see from Apple the reason they selected for requesting the refund.

Basically, I'd like to answer the following question:

"Why did Apple think it was justified to refund this user's money?"

I'm guessing it would be a helpful piece of information for us; if there's something wrong with the app and we're not aware, this could help us fix it. Does anybody know how/if that information is available?

Comment: Can someone explain why the down vote?

Comment: Hi there, the usual thing is that the user explains Apple why they want their money back. That info doesn't arrive to the dev. You should contact Apple directly. They may help you or not, but if you state that you want to give a better service, it's possible that they "collaborate". By the way, Apple usually refunds all the apps if they have just been purchased. But we don't know their restrictions to what app returns should be refunded and which shouldn't.

Comment: Down votes likely because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Not a programming question. Also you're never going to get an answer. Apple won't tell you and people here can only guess. Apple doesn't give refunds often and makes it quite difficult. Your question is probably better directed to them.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons I very much disagree that this isn't a relevant question. Specifically, the "ask help" rules state a question is valid if it relates to software tools commonly used by programmers and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. The Apple App Store is a software tool directly related to programming. Where else would I ask this question?

Answer (score 8):

I did what Injuanj suggested and contacted Apple directly.

Here's their (completely unhelpful) response:

> Thank you for contacting us about your Sales and Trends reports.
>
> I understand that you are wanting more information regarding refunds.
>
> You can find Refund information for your content by filtering your Top
>   Content dashboard to Transaction Type > Refund. Refunds will be
>   indicated as negative values.
>
> Apple does not provide customer or refund information at this time.
>
> If you have further questions regarding your sales reports, please let
>   us know. We're happy to help.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Julie
>
> iTunes Provider Support

1. I already knew how to view my refund/return count, which is how I knew to send the email in the first place!
2. I didn't ask for customer information. I know Apple's not going to give that. Duh. I actually specified this in my original email.
3. I guess the real answer here is this:

> Apple does not provide customer or refund information at this time.